# How to use Pandas to make time series to show performance decline?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

Working with this dataset (text version below):
[image]

I want to create a time series to look at which team's performance declined the most over time. So basically I want to do this by seeing which team had the most decline in points accumulated per year.
I have converted the date column to DateTime but now I cannot figure out how to group the data by date and points (or if that is even the right way to approach this). So far I have tried:

```
df.groupby(['date'])['points_home'].agg(['sum', 'count']).reset_index()
```

However, this is not really giving me what I want. Anyone have any recommendations as to how I should go on about making a time series to show decline in points earned per year?

for reference here is the data in text version:

```
date    home_team   away_team   home_score  away_score  tournament  city    country neutral total_goals points_home points_away
0   1872-11-30  Scotland    England 0   0   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   0   1.0 1.0
1   1873-03-08  England     Scotland    4   2   Friendly    London  England False   6   3.0 0.0
2   1874-03-07  Scotland    England 2   1   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   3   3.0 0.0
3   1875-03-06  England     Scotland    2   2   Friendly    London  England False   4   1.0 1.0
4   1876-03-04  Scotland    England 3   0   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   3   3.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the objective correctly, you would need to re-shape the data frame before summarizing.

First, create a new data frame with three columns:  date, team and points.

```
    df_h = (df.filter(['date', 'home_team', 'home_points'])
              .rename(columns={'home_team': 'team', 
                               'home_points': 'points'}))
    df_a = (df.filter(['date', 'away_team', 'away_points'])
              .rename(columns={'away_team': 'team', 
                               'away_points': 'points'}))
    
    df_2 = pd.concat([df_h, df_a])
```

Second, convert dates to row labels and teams to column labels (with `pivot()`) and calculate yearly amounts (with `resample()`):

```
    df_2 = df_2.pivot(index='date', columns='team', values='points')
    df_2 = df_2.resample('1Y').sum()
```

Now, you can plot each team's accumulated number of points vs date.

```
    df_2.cumsum().plot();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time series graphs, I have 12 times a year, 10 years of data for 5 countries, as appropriate. The sample data is in long format, so I converted it to wide format, and made a data frame for the graph. Depending on the state of your data, you can decide which part of it you want to use.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

date_rng = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2020-01-01', freq='1M')
team = ['England','Scotland','Wales','Germany','Spain']
home = random.choices(team, k=120)
away = random.choices(team, k=120)
home_points = random.choices([3,1,0], k=120)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':date_rng,'home':home,'away':away, 'home_points':home_points})

def away_point(x):
    if x == 3:
        return 0
    elif x == 1:
        return 1
    elif x == 0:
        return 3
df['away_points'] = df['home_points'].apply(away_point)
df_ha = df.melt(id_vars='date', var_name=['home/away'], value_vars=['home','away'], value_name='team')
df_p = df.melt(id_vars='date', var_name=['home_p/away_p'], value_vars=['home_points','away_points'], value_name='points')
df_all = pd.concat([df_ha, df_p], keys='date', axis=1)
df_all.columns = ['date','home/away','team','tmp_date','home_p/away_p','points']
df_all.drop('tmp_date', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_all['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_all['date'])
df_all['yyyy'] = df_all['date'].dt.year
df_plot = df_all.groupby(['yyyy','team']).agg(all_points=('points','sum')).reset_index()
df_plot = df_plot.set_index(['yyyy','team']).unstack(level=1)
df_plot
    all_points
team    England Germany Scotland    Spain   Wales
yyyy                    
2010    7   5   4   7   9
2011    7   2   12  6   6
2012    12  7   4   7   2
2013    0   9   6   10  9
2014    11  5   4   6   7
2015    7   3   2   5   9
2016    7   5   7   3   9
2017    11  4   5   6   6
2018    1   13  9   3   4
2019    9   10  5   4   2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df_plot.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)
ax.legend(frameon=False, ncol=5, loc='upper center', fontsize=6)
```

[image]